# moving objects via the GUI

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a urdf model that when I open in Gazebo if I move it with the movement tool jumps back to its original pose. I am using Gazebo 1.9. Has anyone experienced this issue. Here is the urdf file. The model opens fine in Rviz and displays correctly in Gazebo but can not be moved.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Revolute-Revolute Manipulator -->
<robot name="rrbot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- Import all Gazebo-customization elements, including Gazebo colors -->
  <xacro:include filename="$(find rrbot_description)/urdf/rrbot.gazebo" />
  <!-- Import Rviz colors -->
  <xacro:include filename="$(find rrbot_description)/urdf/materials.xacro" />

  <!-- Used for fixing robot to Gazebo 'base_link' -->
  <link name="world"/>


  <joint name="worldhook" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
  </joint>

   <link name='base_link'>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1 " rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box  size=".4 .2 .1">
            <size>.4 .2 .1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual name='visual'>
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1 " rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box  size=".4 .2 .1">
            <size>.4 .2 .1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <collision name='caster_collision'>
        <origin xyz="-0.15 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <sphere radius=".05">
          <radius>.05</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>

        <surface>
         <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>0</mu>
            <mu2>0</mu2>
            <slip1>1.0</slip1>
            <slip2>1.0</slip2>
          </ode>
         </friction>
        </surface>

      </collision>

      <visual name='caster_visual'>
        <origin xyz="-0.15 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <sphere radius=".05">
            <radius>.05</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

     <inertial>
        <mass value="1e-5" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1 " rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
     </inertial>
  </link> 


    
  <link name="left_wheel">
    <collision name="collision">
      <origin xyz="0.1 0.13 0.0" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05">
          <radius>.1</radius>
          <length>.05</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <origin xyz="0.1 0.13 0.0" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05">
          <radius>.1</radius>
          <length>.05</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0.1 0.13 0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <link name="right_wheel">
    <collision name="collision">
      <origin xyz="0.1 -0.13 0.0" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05">
          <radius>.1</radius>
          <length>.05</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <origin xyz="0.1 -0.13 0.0" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05">
          <radius>.1</radius>
          <length>.05</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0.1 -0.13 0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

 
  <joint type="revolute" name="joint1">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <child link="left_wheel">left_wheel</child>
    <parent link="base_link">base_link</parent>
    <axis xyz="0 4 0">
      <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
    </axis>
    <limit effort="30" velocity="1.0"  />
  </joint>

  <joint type="revolute" name="joint2">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0." rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <child link="right_wheel">right_wheel</child>
     <parent link="base_link">base_link</parent>
     <axis xyz="0 1 0">
      <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
    </axis>
    <limit effort="30" velocity="1.0"  />
  </joint>

  <transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint1"/>
    <actuator name="motor1">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>

  <transmission name="tran2">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint2"/>
    <actuator name="motor2">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>


</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4104/moving-objects-via-the-gui/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

The Problem is in this Code-Snippet on the top of your file

```
<!-- Used for fixing robot to Gazebo 'base_link' -->
  <link name="world"/>


  <joint name="worldhook" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="hector1_base_link"/>
  </joint>
```

The Link references to the Gazebo World and your link is in a fixed position to it.
Try to remove the code from the URDF-file.
if removing this creates Problems with the robot, you can just add a dummy-link as reference frame for your robot

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on 2013-08-08**:
thanks...works ; I have one more issue published under different topic but related. Thank for moving me along.